# How to add simplices to a scipy Delaunay triangulation object

Tags: python, scipy, computational-geometry, scipy-spatial

I already have a rectangle triangulated by a `scipy.spatial.Delaunay()` object. I manage to stretch and curve it around so that it looks like an annulus cut along a line. Here is some code to make something with the same topology:

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay

NR = 22
NTheta = 36

Rin = 1
Rout = 3
alphaFactor = 33/64
alpha = np.pi/alphaFactor # opening angle of wedge

u=np.linspace(pi/2, pi/2 + alpha, NTheta)
v=np.linspace(Rin, Rout, NR)
u,v=np.meshgrid(u,v)
u=u.flatten()
v=v.flatten()

#evaluate the parameterization at the flattened u and v
x=v*np.cos(u)
y=v*np.sin(u)

#define 2D points, as input data for the Delaunay triangulation of U
points2D=np.vstack([u,v]).T
xy0 = np.vstack([x,y]).T
triLattice = Delaunay(points2D) #triangulate the rectangle U
triSimplices = triLattice.simplices
plt.figure()
plt.triplot(x, y, triSimplices, linewidth=0.5)
```

[image: Cut annulus]

Starting from this topology, I now want to join up the two open edges, and make a closed annulus (change the topology, that is). How do I manually add new triangles to the existing triangulation?

Comment: how do you want to use the triangulation afterwards? Has it to be a valid `scipy.spatial.qhull.Delaunay` object (for instance use the `find_simplex` method), or to have the list of triangles is enough?

Comment: could you share your code or a stripped down version? One way of doing this would be to change the node references but without your code handy it makes it difficult to see what is stored where

Comment: @xdze2 Thanks for bringing that up. It does not need to be a valid `Delaunay` object. I just need a modified list of simplices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to merge the points around the gap. Here is a way to do this, by keeping track of the indexes of the corresponding points:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import numpy as np

NR = 4
NTheta = 16

Rin = 1
Rout = 3
alphaFactor = 33/64  # -- set to .5 to close the gap
alpha = np.pi/alphaFactor  # opening angle of wedge

u = np.linspace(np.pi/2, np.pi/2 + alpha, NTheta)
v = np.linspace(Rin, Rout, NR)
u_grid, v_grid = np.meshgrid(u, v)
u = u_grid.flatten()
v = v_grid.flatten()

# Get the indexes of the points on the first and last columns:
idx_grid_first = (np.arange(u_grid.shape[0]),
                  np.zeros(u_grid.shape[0], dtype=int))

idx_grid_last = (np.arange(u_grid.shape[0]),
                 (u_grid.shape[1]-1)*np.ones(u_grid.shape[0], dtype=int))

# Convert these 2D indexes to 1D indexes, on the flatten array:
idx_flat_first = np.ravel_multi_index(idx_grid_first, u_grid.shape)
idx_flat_last = np.ravel_multi_index(idx_grid_last, u_grid.shape)

# Evaluate the parameterization at the flattened u and v
x = v * np.cos(u)
y = v * np.sin(u)

# Define 2D points, as input data for the Delaunay triangulation of U
points2D = np.vstack([u, v]).T
triLattice = Delaunay(points2D) # triangulate the rectangle U
triSimplices = triLattice.simplices

# Replace the 'last' index by the corresponding 'first':
triSimplices_merged = triSimplices.copy()
for i_first, i_last in zip(idx_flat_first, idx_flat_last):
    triSimplices_merged[triSimplices == i_last] = i_first

# Graph
plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
plt.triplot(x, y, triSimplices, linewidth=0.5)
plt.triplot(x, y, triSimplices_merged, linewidth=0.5, color='k')
plt.axis('equal');

plt.plot(x[idx_flat_first], y[idx_flat_first], 'or', label='first')
plt.plot(x[idx_flat_last], y[idx_flat_last], 'ob', label='last')
plt.legend();
```

which gives:

[image: merged mesh]

Maybe you will have to adjust the definition of the `alphaFactor` so that the gap has the right size.